# C to Perl conversion of *ptr++

Tags: c, perl

I have a pointer to an array and either need to change the code considerably to make this work, or just figure out what the equivilent of the statement below is...

```
ptr = array;
*ptr++ = value;
```

So far I have most of it

```
$ptr = \@array;
$$ptr = $value;
```

but this doesn't increment the pointer. What do I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no pointers in Perl. What you have is:

```
my $ary_ref = \@array;
```

`$ary_ref` is now a reference to `@array`. You cannot dereference `$ary_ref` to get a scalar.

You can, however, iterate through the elements of `@array` in a variety of ways. For example, if you want, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @array;

my $ptr = sub {
    my ($i, $ref, $val, $size) = (0, @_);
    sub { $i < $size ? $ref->[$i ++ ] = $val : () }
}->(\@array, deadbeaf => 10);

1 while defined $ptr->();

use YAML;
print Dump \@array;
```

By the way, there is no reason you can't write

```
p[i] = value;
i++;
```

in C. In Perl, it might become:

```
$array[$_] = $value for 0 .. $#array;
```

or,

```
@array = ($value) x @array;
```

or,

```
$_ = value for @array;
```

etc. You should explain what the overall goal is rather than asking about a specific statement in C.

Comment: That's a little on the evil side for a beginner question.

Comment: Sure, it is, but it is par for the course. `*ptr++ = value;` is no less evil.

Comment: After reading through the C-code a little more I realized the line-by-line conversion idea was pretty stupid and went with a simpler non-array/pointer/concat method.

Comment: I really like @SinanÜnür's code snippet. Would definitly use it to confuse people... heh

Comment: By the way, this is a simple question. I was simply looking for a simple answer like, "Perl does not support pointer incrementing, because Perl does not support pointers..."

Comment: @EricFossum The simplest answer, would also be the least helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The C code modifies the first element of `array` and will likely change at least some part of the rest of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int array[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  int value = 42;
  int *ptr;
  int i;

  ptr = array;
  *ptr++ = value;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); i++)
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  puts("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
42 0 0 0 0
```

Perl has references rather than pointers. References cannot be null, but there’s no reference arithmetic.

Modifying the first element of an array in Perl looks like

```
$ perl -wle '@a=(0)x5; $a[0] = 42; print "@a"'
42 0 0 0 0
```

or to be excessively literal

```
$ perl -wle '@a=(0)x5; $ptr = \$a[0]; $$ptr = 42; print "@a"'
42 0 0 0 0
```

Your question gives a single bookkeeping detail of the C code. What’s the broader context? What’s the C code doing?

In general, don’t write C in Perl. Considered broadly, C code tends to process arrays one item at a time, but Perl modifies the entire conceptual chunk, *e.g.*, with a regex for strings or [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) or [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to transform entire arrays.